# Mouse flicker when trying to use a non-modifier key and dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, drag

There's been a recent trend to use spacebar as a meta key while performing certain drag actions in more graphical apps.

The problem is that the mouse flickers while holding spacebar (or any non-modifier key) down and moving your mouse: http://jsfiddle.net/S3AJr/4/

Example code:

```
$(function() {
    var count = 1,
        isSpaceBarPressed = false;

    $('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.which === 32) {
            isSpaceBarPressed = true;
        }
    });

    $('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.which === 32) {
            isSpaceBarPressed = false;
        }
    });

    $('body').on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (isSpaceBarPressed) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.pizza').text(count++);
        }
    });
});
```

Is there a way to fix this or am I limited to ctrl, alt, shift and meta?

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix bro!

```
// note include underscore-min.js for our throttle function

$(function () {
    var count = 1,
        isSpaceBarPressed = false;

    var throttledRender = _.throttle(function () {
        $('.pizza').text(count);
    }, 200);

    $('body').on('keydown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.which === 32) {
            isSpaceBarPressed = true;
        }
    });

    $('body').on('keyup', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.which === 32) {
            isSpaceBarPressed = false;
        }
    });

    $('body').on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (isSpaceBarPressed) {
            e.preventDefault();
            count++;
            throttledRender();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that you are rendering WAY too often (every time the event fires).  Instead, you want to increment your variable every time but only render periodically.  See this [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3AJr/5/) using [underscore's throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) function.  If you prefer, there is a [jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) for this too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my mouse pointer still flickers. Also, this occurs in apps without re-rendering that only apply transformations to an SVG viewbox.

Comment: Which OS & browser?  I'm not getting any flicker in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: I am using Chrome and OSX

Comment: I had to test this on my mac at home.  You might be out of luck on this one.  Looks like a low-level Chrome thing.  I removed all extensions and plugins, restarted Chrome and it's still flickering when the space key is down.  Even if you use e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropogation().

Comment: I tested on WinXP, Win7 and Win8 and didn't see this behavior on any of them.

Comment: like I said, chrome on OSX.